# How to use Cross Join to query data in CnosDB？

Tags: cnosdb

I try to use cross join to query data in CnosDB. But I failed.

```sql
create table air(pressure double, tags(station));
select * from air a1, air a2;
```

Result:

```
"422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {\"error_code\":\"010001\",\"error_message\":\"Datafusion: reject_cross_join\\ncaused by\\nInternal error: Optimizer rule 'reject_cross_join' failed due to unexpected error: This feature is not implemented: cross join. This was likely caused by a bug in DataFusion's code and we would welcome that you file an bug report in our issue tracker\"}"
```

However I noticed that natural joins are supported.

```sql
select * from air a1 join air a2 on a1.station = a2.station;
```

```
Query took 0.051 seconds.
```

How to use cross join to query data in CnosDB?